How to exclude some symbols from DLL when linking with a program?
I have a C++ program that I'm trying to link with a rather complicated DLL.  When I link the DLL directly in visual studio, I get a number of errors telling me about symbols being "already defined".  These are not the "exported" DLL symbols, but rather some dependencies several layers deep.
However, I discovered that instead of linking this DLL when I compile/link the program, I can successfully load it dynamically using the Windows LoadLibrary() function and execute the exported functions without conflict.
My question is, is there a way to link this DLL at compile/link time and exclude the symbols that are conflicting (since my program doesn't need to directly access them anyway), and only pull in the exported symbols?

In your linker settings for additional options you can add /FORCE:MULTIPLE 

@user20716902 Thank you.  Is there a way to only apply /FORCE:MULTIPLE with respect to certain symbols or that DLL?  I would want to be aware of any other multiple symbols from other sources.

Shouldn't this be done in target_link_libraries if you are using CMake?

@JoshuaLewis Yes, that is exactly what I'm doing in cmake to link the libraries (when not using LoadLibrary() dynamically)

You're linking with .lib files.  If the symbols aren't from your library, you shouldn't see this error (only if you're building the .dll - but I doubt that's the case here). Are you also linking with one of its dependencies? More context (error message - which shows the symbols and their source, or even a mock-up) would help.
